# Prohibit dot in front of @ in email regexp validation

Tags: regex

I would like to prohibit `.` in front of the `@` in email validation in javascript.

What I have:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

So `email.@domain.com` is prohibited, but `email.email@domain.com` should be accepted.

What could I do?

Comment: Why would you "validate" email addresses based on your own loose idea of how a valid email address looks like? See [How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: what do you mean loose idea?   dot is not allowed in front of @

Comment: Yes, `.` is not allowed in front of `@`.  There are many many many many rules about what is a valid regex. Far better to use existing code than rolling your own.

Comment: My email has . in front of the @ and I send and receive emails all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is slightly modified version of your regex. Basically, `^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)` was changed to `^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)*`:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)*@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```